# IONIC API Undefined

Tags: json, angular, api, ionic-framework

I have an **IONIC APP** with **CORDOVA**. I Just want to **GET a JSON** from an **URL**.

*I Created a service call* `rest.service.ts`

> rest.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestService {

  BASE_URL = 'http://whatever.....';

  constructor(public http: HTTP) {}

  getProjects() {

    const URL = this.BASE_URL + 'getProjects';

    this.http.get(URL, {}, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
      .then(answer => {

        return JSON.parse(answer.data);

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.status);
        console.log(error.error); // error message as string
        console.log(error.headers);
      });

  }

}
```

Here in this file I can see the info. If I insert something like...

`console.log(JSON.parse(answer.data));`

I can see the results in **JSON just as I Want.**

*The problem is when I try to use this methods in other files...*

> otherpage.page.ts

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RestService } from './../rest.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-otherpage',
  templateUrl: './otheropage .page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./otherpage .page.scss']
})
export class OtherPage implements OnInit {

  projects;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public rest: RestService,
  ) {


    this.projects = this.rest.getProjects();
    console.log(this.projects); // UNDEFINED

  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Here... `this.projects`... is **undefined**... **¿What is happening?** I tried `platform.ready`, insert in `ngOnInit`... nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the service and subscribe this service your page.

```
 BASE_URL = 'http://whatever.....';
 getProjects() {
    const URL = this.BASE_URL + 'getProjects';
    return this.http.get(URL, {}, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  }
```

Subscribe this service observable in your page.ts file.

```
this.rest.getProjects().subscribe((answer)=>{
    this.projects = JSON.parse(answer.data);
    console.log(this.projects); // here you get the json 
},error=>{
    consoole.log(error)
});
```

Note:

> console.log(this.projects); // UNDEFINED
>   Because this line executes before the http observable send the response, you need to subscribe that http observable to get the json.

Comment: Thanks you. Just the subscribe() method does not exists. I used .then(). I just wanted to simplify my page.ts file as much as possible so I didnt think about that. I just wanted to do all the API job in my Rest file. But It's working fine now! Thanki